# Update array of object fields in nodejs

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongoose

**JSON document:**

```
{
    "_id" :
    "description": "task1",
    "completed": false,
    "subTask": [
        {
            "taskID": "01",
            "subTaskCompletion": "false",
            "subTaskDescription": "task 1 sub task 1 desc"
        },
        {
            "taskID": "02",
            "subTaskCompletion": "false",
            "subTaskDescription": "task 1 sub task 2 desc"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm able to update the "description" and "completed" with the following code:

**Node.js:**

```
router.patch('/tasks/:id', auth, async (req, res) => {
    const updates = Object.keys(req.body)
    const allowedUpdates = ['description', 'completed']
    const isValidOperation = updates.every((update) => allowedUpdates.includes(update))

    if (!isValidOperation) {
        return res.status(400).send({ error: 'Invalid updates!' })
    }

    try {
        const task = await Task.findOne({ _id: req.params.id})

        if (!task) {
            return res.status(404).send()
        }

        updates.forEach((update) => task[update] = req.body[update])
        await task.save()
        res.send(task)
    } catch (e) {
        res.status(400).send(e)
    }
})
```

I'm passing in these as the request body

```
{
    "description": "task modified",
    "completed": true
}
```

However, I couldn't find a way to update the "subTaskCompletion" to "true" for subTask with "taskID" of "01"

Answer (score 0):

You can try this -

```
router.patch('/tasks/:id', auth, async (req, res) => {
const updates = Object.keys(req.body)
const allowedUpdates = ['description', 'completed', 'subTask']
const isValidOperation = updates.every((update) => allowedUpdates.includes(update))

if (!isValidOperation) {
    return res.status(400).send({ error: 'Invalid updates!' })
}

try {
    const task = await Task.findOne({ _id: req.params.id})

    if (!task) {
        return res.status(404).send()
    }

    updates.forEach((update) => {
      task[update] = update === 'subTask' 
        ? task[update].map(subTask => subTask.taskID === req.body[update].taskID ? req.body[update] : subTask)
        : req.body[update]
    })
    await task.save()
    res.send(task)
} catch (e) {
    res.status(400).send(e)
}
```

and pass this

```
{
"description": "task modified",
"completed": true,
"subTask": {
    "taskID": "01",
    "subTaskCompletion": "true"
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks ofriman. I've forgot to mention that there are other fields in the subTask and it's compulsory to pass in other fields using your method. Is there a way to pass in only the fields which needs to be updated only? The provided answer is able to work if I pass in each and every value in the subTask --> "taskID": "01","subTaskCompletion": "true"
 ,"subTaskDescription": "task 1 sub task 2 desc"

Comment: task[update].map(subTask => subTask.taskID === req.body[update].taskID ? {...subTask, ...req.body[update]} : subTask)

Comment: getting error "Cast to Array failed for value..." and (node:71507) [DEP0079] DeprecationWarning: Custom inspection function on Objects via .inspect() is deprecated

Comment: this issue related to mongo lib -  Check this 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40806361/validation-error-mongodb/40839537#40839537.

Answer (score 0):

Add a new field to your request body, that field includes sub task ids what you want to mark as done.

In example, the field called `markSubTasksDone` then your code need come to:

```
router.patch('/tasks/:id', auth, async (req, res) => {
  const updates = Object.keys(req.body)
  const allowedUpdates = ['description', 'completed', 'markSubTasksDone'] // add a new field
  const isValidOperation = updates.every((update) => allowedUpdates.includes(update))

  if (!isValidOperation) {
    return res.status(400).send({ error: 'Invalid updates!' })
  }

  try {
    const task = await Task.findOne({ _id: req.params.id })

    if (!task) {
      return res.status(404).send()
    }

    updates.forEach((update) => task[update] && (task[update] = req.body[update])) // make sure `update` property is exist

    // mark subTask as done
    const listSubTaskIds = req.body.markSubTasksDone
    if (listSubTaskIds && listSubTaskIds.length) {
      listSubTaskIds.forEach(taskId => {
        const subTask = task.subTask.find(i => i.taskId === taskId)
        if (subTask) {
          subTask.subTaskCompletion = true;
        }
      });
    }

    await task.save()
    res.send(task)
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(400).send(e)
  }
})
```

And request body:

```
{
  "description": "task modified",
  "completed": true,
  "markSubTasksDone": ["01"]
}
```